# pandas TypeError: invalid type comparison when comparing datetime64 when using nunique

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I tried to use `nunique` on `datetime64`, but got error,

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

on the the code,

```
np.where(df.groupby('group_id')['payment_date'].transform('nunique') == 1, 0, 10)
```

I tried to check if the `datetime64` values are all the same. The `df` looks like,

```
group_id    date
   1        2017-10-01
   1        2017-10-02
   1        2017-10-03
   1        2017-10-03
   2        2017-11-01
   2        2017-10-15
   2        2017-11-05
```

I am wondering how to fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with the fact that the resultant output of `nunique` is coerced to datetime to preserve the dtype. Shouldn't happen if you ask me.

The workaround is to do an `nunique` comparison on the string data:

```
df.date.astype(str).groupby(df.group_id).transform('nunique')
```

The rest follows from here as usual.

Comment: will get `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'date'`, so has to `astype(str)` for `date`, and then `df.groupby(df.group_id)`